# Tomcat - Assign roles based on client ip address in my custom realm

Tags: java, tomcat, authentication

I am trying to create a custom realm based on certificate authentication. I want to allow clients to connect if they present a trusted certificate. This is no problem and there are plenty of examples on how to do this.

However, I need to assign different roles depending on the client IP address, but I can't figure out how to access the request or any other object holding the client IP address from within the realm.

How can this be achieved?